# Count instances of letter or number in a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to count instances of numbers from a number in a cell.
For expample we have the number 78812557839. I need a formula or function to count how many instances of 7,8,1,2,5,3,9 this long number consist of, i.e. 8-3 instances, 5-2,7-2,9-1 etc.
Thanks for a tip in this regard.

Comment: Here's an [aswer](http://superuser.com/questions/469166/counting-occurences-of-a-character-in-an-excel-spreadsheet) for you, just pass a sigle cell to that formula instead of a range.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Apparently sometimes we all think to complicated while answers are that easy as yours. Solved!

Comment: If you stay on this site, make sure you upvote that question and answer when you have enough reputation. That way it will be easier for others to find.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, In **C1** enter:

`=ROW()-1` and copy down

In **D1** enter:

```
=LEN(A$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A$1,C1,""))
```

and copy down.  Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know you could use `ROW` without an argument.

Comment: @benshepherd  I am taking advantage of the **position** of the formula.....a much better approach would be to use `=ROWS($1:1)-1` because it can be placed in ANY row and copied down.